# Heroku gem api scaling workers response 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, resque

I am using the [gem "heroku-resque-auto-scale"](https://github.com/mirthlab/heroku-resque-auto-scale) to scale workers.

In resque I can see all jobs are failed:

```
RestClient::UnprocessableEntity
Error
422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Here is the full error log: http://pastie.org/private/tpgptsgbcvroyjy5n35lgw

What does this error mean?

I have created a Procfile with:

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=10 bundle exec rake resque:work
```

The Heroku rails app is on a cedar stack.
I would like when there are no jobs that the Heroku workers are set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heroku gem is deprected switched to the heroku-api gem and it works fine.